# How to pull data by inner joining two DB2 table using pyspark?

Tags: db2, pyspark

I'm using following query to pull data from DB2

```
SELECT A.Emp_ID,B1.Manager_Name,B1.Manager_Phone,B1.Manager_mail
FROM Employee A
INNER JOIN Manager_DETAIL B1
ON (B1.EMP_ID = A.EMP_ID
OR B1.Manager_mail = A.SuperVisor_mail
AND B1.Join_year = '2017' AND B1.QTR = 'Q1' 
AND B1.Dept_Name
IN ('support')
```

How do I do same thing using pyspark?

I tried with this code

```
tab_A= spark.read.jdbc("My Connection String","Employee",
             properties={"user": "my user id", 
                      "password": "my passwore",
                      'driver' : 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'})

tab_A.registerTempTable('data_table')
# query to get columns necessary to create indexes
sql = "SELECT * FROM data_table"
A = spark.sql(sql)

tab_B= spark.read.jdbc("My Connection String","Manager_DETAIL",
             properties={"user": "my user id", 
                      "password": "my passwore",
                      'driver' : 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'})

tab_B.registerTempTable('data_table1')
# query to get columns necessary to create indexes
sql = "SELECT * FROM data_table1"
B1 = spark.sql(sql)
C=spark.sql("SELECT A.Emp_ID,B1.Manager_Name,B1.Manager_Phone,B1.Manager_mail
FROM  A
INNER JOIN B1
ON (B1.EMP_ID == A.EMP_ID) |\
(B1.Manager_mail == A.SuperVisor_mail) \
& (B1.Join_year == '2017' & B1.QTR == 'Q1') \ 
& B1.Dept_Name IN ('support')")
```

But I'm getting invalid syntax error

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: After modifying my query by replacing A with data_table & B1 with data_table1 my query is working if I'm putting only one condition. But it is not working with multiple AND OR condition. Am I doing any mistake in And OR symbol? Kindly suggest